# Cannot rename disk resource

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a system running Ubuntu 8.04.2. I am trying to rename a folder using the mv command but continually get a "cannot move 'x' to 'x.old': Device or resource busy" message, even when running via sudo. When I run "fuser -m /path/to/x" I get nothing listed. I don't have lsof installed (and can't install it). I am not sure how to find out what is blocking me from being able to move this resource. Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Um... you do realize that [Ubuntu 8.04 is over *eight years old*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_8.04_LTS_.28Hardy_Heron.29), right? In computer terms, that's practically an eternity.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. You can only do so much with inherited systems. This was originally a JumpBox VM so it's pretty tied down as to what I am even able to do with it. The intent of this entire project is to update the mediawiki on the box and migrate it to a newer server.

Comment: is it a plain folder, not a mount point ?

Comment: @Archemar Good call! I just checked the mounts and see that it it, indeed mounted.

Comment: @Archemar Your suggestion resolved my problem but I can't mark it as the answer because it's a comment.

Comment: Ill make it an answer sometime later then.

Comment: Michael, you'll be pleased to know that my project was successful. The wiki had been migrated to a shiny new CentOS server with all the latest and greatest of the LAMP stack. Thank you, @archemar for your help.